# Dependency problems installing eViacam on 12.04

Tags: apt, dependencies, opencv

I used [eViacam](http://eviacam.sourceforge.net/index.php) in windows, but now I'm using (L)ubuntu 12.04, and I fail to install. I found a guide to install it on ubuntu 11.10, but I have unsolved dependencies.

Error runing "`sudo apt-get install libcv2.1 libhighgui2.1 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0`"

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libcv2.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libhighgui2.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libcv2.1' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libhighgui2.1' has no installation candidate
```

[LINK TO THE GUIDE](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/01/eviacam-1-5-3-mouse-replacement-software-move-mouse-pointer-using-your-head.html)

EDIT:

I've aded their repository, and updated. unsolved depencies again:

```
ergo@ikarusII:~$ sudo apt-get install eviacam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Recommended packages:
  wx2.8-i18n
The following packages will be upgraded:
  eviacam
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 88 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 5,235 kB of archives.
After this operation, 468 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cesar-crea-si/eviacam/ubuntu/ precise/main eviacam i386 1.5.4-0ubuntu1~precise [5,235 kB]
Fetched 5,235 kB in 18s (287 kB/s)                                             
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of eviacam:
 eviacam depends on libcv2.1; however:
  Package libcv2.1 is not installed.
 eviacam depends on libhighgui2.1; however:
  Package libhighgui2.1 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing eviacam (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 eviacam
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

libcv2.1 isn't available on Ubuntu 12.04 (according to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libcv&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) it was replaced by libcv2.3). You'll need to contact the author of that PPA, which it seems the only way to do so is via their [forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eviacam/forums/forum/898005) and ask if eViacam is compatible with libcv2.3 and if so, if they will update their packaging in the PPA to depend on that package rather than libcv2.1.

The same thing happened for libhighgui2.1 (it was replaced by libhighgui2.3) so you'll want to ask about it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update - I followed these instructions from [the eviacam site:](http://eviacam.sourceforge.net/)

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cesar-crea-si/eviacam
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install eviacam

and it installed fine on Gnome Ubuntu 14.04, so the dependency problem mentioned by @tgm4883 must have been solved.